# How can I get a user's Fan pages via API calls?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

I have created two fan pages on Facebook using my Facebook id, and now I want to get those pages via JavaScript.  How can I do this with the Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Answer (score 0):

you can query that via graph api via '/me/accounts'

Answer (score 0):

Following the [photo-albums example](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/photo-albums), this is a quick sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Pages list</title>
</head>
<body>
<fb:login-button perms="manage_pages"
                 onlogin="getPages()">
  Grant Permissions to Allow access to Pages</fb:login-button>
<ul id="pages"></ul>

<script>
window.getPages = function() {
    FB.api('/me/accounts', function(resp) {
        var ul = document.getElementById('pages');
        for (var i=0, l=resp.data.length; i<l; i++) {
            var
            page= resp.data[i];
            li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = "Name: " + page.name + "<br /> Category: " + page.category;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    });
};
</script>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
 FB.init({ 
    appId:'APP_ID_HERE', cookie:true, 
    status:true, xfbml:true 
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `page` object contains the following fields: `name`, `id`, `category` and `access_token`